# Adding a column in a raster attribute table in R to make a categorical one

Tags: raster, r

```
#Get the names of all the files with extension ".tif" of the folder
files <- list.files("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\RCP26_2020\\", pattern='.tif$', full.names=TRUE )
files
Raster_stack <- stack(files)
Raster_stack
compareCRS(Nepal, Raster_stack)

#Crop stack by Nepal
Stack_Nepal <- crop(Raster_stack, Nepal)
Stack_Nepal

final_lulc <- calc(Stack_Nepal, which.max)
final_lulc
plot(final_lulc)

#Masking by a shapefile
masked <- mask(x = final_lulc, mask = Nepal)
plot(masked)
is.factor(masked)
as.factor(masked)

#Its result is:
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 495, 978, 484110  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
extent     : 80.05833, 88.20833, 26.35, 30.475  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : 1, 10  (min, max)
attributes :
       ID
 from:  1
  to : 10
```

Now, instead of values from 1 to 10 in attributes of ID, I want to add another column for landuse and land covers
such as barren, cropland, forest, grass, impervious, shrub,snow, urban, water and wetland respectively.
Can you please help me suggest a code for adding a new colum with these values to make it categorical one?

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty close! Although `as.factor(masked)` should be saved in an object:

```
r <- as.factor(masked)
```

Then, extract the RAT (Raster Attribute Table) with `levels` function, and add a new column with the class data. Finally, save this RAT back to the raster:

```
# extract raster levels
x <- levels(r)[[1]]
# add classes
x$class <- c('barren', 'cropland', 'forest',
             'grass', 'impervious', 'shrub','snow',
             'urban', 'water', 'wetland')
# replace original levels
levels(r) <- x
```

If you want to plot it, use `rasterVis` package:

```
rasterVis::levelplot(r)
```

Comment: Thank you so much.